# How to prevent "re-initialization" of the parent router-outlet while navigating child routes inside? in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a simple application with nested router-outlet and my question is how can i disable "re-initialization" of the parent router-outlet while navigating child routes inside?

Comment: stackblitz please.

Comment: {
    path: 'courses/:id',
    component: CourseDetailComponent,
    children: [   

      {
        path: 'assignments',
        component: AssignmentComponent
      }
    ]

I have defined <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the parent component.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.